Mongoose cursor times out after a couple of hours even though noCursorTimeout flag is set
export const cacheRecommendations = async () => {
    const userCursor = UserModel.find({})
        .cursor()
        .addCursorFlag("noCursorTimeout", true);
    let counter = 0;

    for await (const user of userCursor) {
        console.log("counter", counter);
        counter++;

        await calculateRecommendationsWithTensorflow(user._id);
    }
};

This code iterates over every user in the database. The calculations from calculateRecommendationsWithTensorflow take a couple of minutes per user to complete. It uses a tensorflow model to iterate over many documents to find the best rated ones.
The problem is that randomly after user number 100 I get an error:
cursor id 7158571831382380588 not found. It's always at the same cursor position. At this point the function is running for already round about 9 hours.
When I try to skip the first 99 users, the calculations proceed normally for user 100 and the users afterwards:
export const cacheRecommendations = async () => {
    const userCursor = UserModel.find({})
        .cursor()
        .addCursorFlag("noCursorTimeout", true);
    let counter = 0;

    for await (const user of userCursor) {
        console.log("counter", counter);
        counter++;

        if (counter < 99) continue; // <--- SKIP THE FIRST USERS, THEN THE CURSOR WORKS CORRECTLY

        await calculateRecommendationsWithTensorflow(user._id);
    }
};

It is pretty hard to debug because I didn't find a way to make it fail without waiting 9 hours yet. Another important information might be that the code is invoked in a worker thread, since Tensorflow otherwise blocks the main thread.
If anyone has an idea how to solve this weird bug, I'd be happy to hear about it.

Maybe session is timing out? https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/cursor.noCursorTimeout/#session-idle-timeout-overrides-nocursortimeout

i dont know which clause should make it timeout, though. also, i set the noCursorTimeout  flag.  also, i dont think it is a document that is larger to process, which would go above the max idle time, because if i skip the first documents, then it runs successfully
